# Why my code is showing me 22 After mickey and minnie doe while I am reading newfile.txt in PHP?

Tags: php, file, file-handling, readfile

I overwrote the existed file that is named newfile.txt and I read it using readfile function and coding is working fine also me **22**... and I am not familiar with this...
Could you please tell me and thank you in Advance!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php 
        $myfile=fopen("newfile.txt","w") or die ("Unable to open the file");
        $txt = "Mickey Doe\n";
        fwrite($myfile,$txt);
        $txt = "Minnie Doe\n";
        fwrite($myfile,$txt);
        echo readfile("newfile.txt");
        fclose($myfile);
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

`readfile` outputs the content so you don't have to use `echo` before that. Moreover use `<br>\n` instead of `\n` since you want to display it in HTML context.

Answer (score 1):

PHP function readfile it self do output, and you use echo that cause it show the output character count.you can change your code line as per below :

```
<?php 
        $myfile=fopen("newfile.txt","w") or die ("Unable to open the file");
        $txt = "Mickey Doe\n";
        fwrite($myfile,$txt);
        $txt = "Minnie Doe\n";
        fwrite($myfile,$txt);
        readfile("newfile.txt"); // readfile it self do output you don't need to echo.
        fclose($myfile);
    ?>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What did you change, and why?